# Laravel пагинация сгруппированного результата groupBy()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Есть следующая конструкция:

```
$projects = Project::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        $data['sorted'] = $projects->groupBy(function ($project) {
            return $project->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
});
```

Я получаю следующий результат, сгруппированный по дням (как мне и нужно отображать в шаблоне):

```
Collection {#538 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    "2019-01-28" => Collection {#504 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▶]
    }
    "2019-01-27" => Collection {#539 ▼
      #items: array:24 [▶]
    }
    "2019-01-26" => Collection {#502 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

Мне необходимо сделать пагинацию, так как записей будет много, можно ли сделать стандартными средствами сохраняя при этом группировку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была реализована следующая конструкция, на основе этого примера:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30014621/6405083

```
$page = $request->has('page') ? $request->input('page') : 1; // Use ?page=x if given, otherwise start at 1
        $numPerPage = 15; // Number of results per page
        $count = Project::count(); // Get the total number of entries you'll be paging through
        // Get the actual items
        $projects = Project::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->take($numPerPage)->offset(($page-1)*$numPerPage)->get()->groupBy(function($project) {
                return $project->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
            });
        $data['sorted'] = new Paginator($projects, $count, $numPerPage, $page, ['path' => $request->url(), 'query' => $request->query()]);
```